# latex workshop: is there a way that viewer follows editor and the other way round

Tags: viewers, vscode, latex-workshop

I use latex workshop on VS code combined with okular, but I would not mind using the internal viewer.
I use forward search and backward search.

My question is, whether there is a way to make the editor follow the viewer and the other way round:
If i scroll in the editor, that the viewer shows the according segment
and also if i scroll the viewer that the editor follows?

This would be very convenient.

In the long run, I maybe use latex to create html or what.
Is it possible to do the same with a browser as a viewer?